# Wireless network adapter not working on Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, adapter

*new Ubuntu user here*

I have a dual-boot system with Windows XP and Ubuntu (I don't remember which version exactly, but it's fairly new). I have a wireless network adapter (from Cisco, connected by USB port) that works just great on the Windows side of my system, but I don't know how to get it working on the Ubuntu side. There is no problem with the adapter or the computer (as far as I'm concerned); I'm just not familiar enough with Linux and Ubuntu to get it up and running. Any suggestions?

Comment: please try the answer of Mina Michael, if this does not work please add some more information about the network adapter (model number etc.)

Answer (score 1):

go to "software & updates" from the ubuntu dash, go to the additional drivers tab (furthest to the right), you should see a disabled driver that should be the one related to your network adapter. Enable it.